# Can you add addressables from your script in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-generated-content, addressables

imagine you want a player in your shipped game be able to add different tiles to your game which then would be saved as addressables in a mod folder. This folder could then be shared so others could install it.

How would I make the script add addressables?

Comment: `StreamingAssets` may be a much easier way to handle this. I'm not sure it's possible to create addressables in a player; that's more for building asset packs from within the Editor which are then distributed.

Comment: If you want to interact with addressable assets added like this, you can [load them through the API as usual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.15/manual/LoadingAddressableAssets.html). As 3Dave mentioned, Addressables are intended for in-editor content creation that can be distributed later. If you want a system for user generated mods, you should probably provide some API for users and deserialize things yourself from some known location. You can use Unity to build mods as well, [with a system like the one in Sky Rogue](https://github.com/nihilocrat/SkyRogueModTool)